# linux script argument with letter or number

Tags: linux, shell

I am searching for solution for my script argument problem

Here it the thing:

I would like to start my script with:

```
./myscript.sh -d9 file_name
```

instead of `9`, there could be any other number

Is there some function for dealing things like this?

Comment: And what is the problem? How make your script accept `... -d<number_only> ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the bash shell, take a look at the `getopts` built-in command. Type `help getopts` at the bash prompt to get information about it.

In short, it accepts a list of possible options and whether they take argument values, and it will return the next option to process in a pair of variables. Use it in a while loop to [process all the options](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html), and then you can also process the filename:

```
while getopts "d:" flag
do
  if [ "$flag" = "d" ]
  then
    D=$OPTARG
  fi
done
echo $D    # argument value you are looking for

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
echo $1    # the file name after the parsed options
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using getopt:

```
$ getopt d: -d42 arg
-d 42 -- arg
```

The first parameter is a list of options (the colon means that the option takes an argument)

Comment: getopt cannot handle arguments containing whitespace and is generally considered superseded by getopts.

Answer (score -1):

In your example, `$1` is "-d9" and `$2` is "file_name".

`$@` is "-d9 file_name" and if you ever go over 9, start using `${10}`

Use regexes to find the values.

For instance:

```
if [[ $@ =~ "d (\d+)( |$)" ]]
```

Comment: That is ripe for false positives.